# get the end of an <object> video and add autoplay to it

Tags: html, object, video, iframe

Two, maybe, simple questions:


1. I'm trying to get the end of my video with the function `onended` and don't works because I have an `<object>` like:

```
    <object width="100%" height="100%" id="player_api" data="https://my-url.com" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></object>
```

<del>2. I have my params but If I add `<param name="autoPlay" value="true">` and `<param name="autoStart" value="true">` it doesn't autoplay anyway....</del>

Thanks all.

EDIT: 
This is my full object:

```html
<object width="100%" height="100%" id="player_api" data="https://my-url.com" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
<param name="quality" value="high">
<param name="bgcolor" value="#000000">
<param name="flashvars" value="config={&quot;playlist&quot;:[{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;https://medialibrary-diretteweb-it.s3.amazonaws.com/advert/spot_crsa_40sec.mp4&quot;,&quot;autoPlay&quot;:false}],&quot;clip&quot;:{&quot;autoPlay&quot;:false},&quot;plugins&quot;:{&quot;controls&quot;:{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;https%3A//adserver.tigicongress.com/revive/www/delivery/fc.php%3Fscript%3DdeliveryLog%3AvastServeVideoPlayer%3Aplayer%26file_to_serve%3Dflowplayer/3.1.1/flowplayer.controls-3.1.1.swf&quot;}},&quot;playerId&quot;:&quot;player&quot;}">
<param name="autoPlay" value="true">
<param name="autoStart" value="true">
<param name="ShowControls" value="false">
</object>
```

EDIT 2: My second question I have figure out by myself, I'm still stuck at the first one.

Comment: What is the extension of the video file?

Comment: i think you should remove  type attribute

Comment: @SlaviGalabovthe extension is `.mp4`

Comment: @SlaviGalabov if I remove the `type`, the video start to downloading on load of the page

Comment: i can not reproduce your issue. Please give more info, code

Comment: @SlaviGalabov updated my question ;)

Comment: My second question I have figure out by myself, I'm still stuck at the first one..

Answer (score 0):

```html
<object onended="myFunction()" width="400" height="250" id="player_api" data="https://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4">
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
<param name="quality" value="high">
<param name="bgcolor" value="#000000">
<param name="autoplay" value="true">
<param name="ShowControls" value="true">
</object>
```

Comment: thanks for the hint, I'm going to try, how can I put that inside my object tag? I can't modify it directly. It is generated. :(

Comment: I think don't work, I have tried from chrome console, locally. Also tried `var aud = document.getElementById("player_api");
aud.onended = function() {
    alert("The audio has ended");
};`